# Load big XML files to mySQL database (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, large-files, match

For a new project I need to load big XML files (200MB+) to a mySQL database. There are +- 20 feeds i need to match with that (not all fields are the same).

Now when i want to catch the XML I get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 171296569 bytes) in E:\UsbWebserver\Root\****\application\libraries\MY_xml.php on line 21
```

Is there an easy solution for this? It's not possible to get te feed in parts of a few MB's each.

Thank you very much!

P.s. has somebody an idea to match xml-feeds easy?

Comment: Show us the code where you import the data. Maybe with the use of "unset()" it is possible to reduce the amount of memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't broke up the server ? In the beginnng it will run on a shared server.

Comment: That won't break it, but safe_mode has to be off.

Comment: Lol, I'm not sure the sysadmin would appreciate that.

Comment: @tofutim: I'm sure he doesn't mind since there are easy ways to stop that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to parse big xml files (or big files in general), it's a better strategy to write a stream based function than one that requires everything to be in memory at the same time. PHP has a class called [XmlReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), that allows you to scan through a file, one node at a time. It may not be trivial to change your code to use it, but you might consider making the change.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog entry](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Importing%20huge%20XML%20files%20using%20PHP5%20-%20efficiently%20and%20conveniently.htm) about that a while ago. The solution was to use XMLReader to read chunks of the XML into an object and do things with it then.

Answer (score 0):

Add ini_set('memory_limit', '150MB') into your script.

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP the only programming language you would consider for the job? If you use Java, then there are more and efficient ways to load XML..